# Using Pivot table as a reference to another model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am working on carpool service, so I have the following table schema
the `user`, `cars`, `user_car`(pivot table, it has also additional fields like plate_number) so I can add many cars and the user can select his car from our already added cars and provide additional information. That car will be his car.

Now I have another table `ride` which also takes reference `id` of `cars_user` I have made the relationship between `cars` and `users`. But what will be a relationship between `Ride` and `car_user` model, as `car_user` can be used for many rides?

Comment: Whats the difference between ´car_user´ and ´user_car´, i think you need to edit your question so its more concise...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the pivot table `user_car` has a primary key column it should look something like:

```
id, user_id, car_id
```

Implement a `UserCar` model for that table.

Then attach a relation to this model on your `Ride` model something like

```php
public function user_car(){

    return belongsTo('\App\UserCar', 'user_car_id', 'id');

}
```

You can also then, use the assignation to review the rides of that pivot table

On your `UserCar` Model you can have something like this:

```php
public function rides(){

    return hasMany('\App\Ride', 'user_car_id', 'id');

}
```

You can reference it as any other model now, from your `User` and `Car` models.

I personally would call this table and model something else, like `car_assignations`, `CarAssignation`, but that's your choice.

Comment: How would you query the rides from the User model?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, there's many ways to do that, the current answer doesn't allow for that, but you could set up a HasManyThrough relationship, or use the with() method to load "sub relations", or you could just write sql and make a join, or make a join with eloquent. Many many ways

Answer (score 0):

you should define pivot for 3 table cars, users, ride in every three model you create 2 relation to other two table
so your pivot table has three column as user_id, car_id, ride_id
and for example your user model is like:

```
public function car() {
return $this->belongsToMany('car', 'user_car_ride');
}

public function ride() {
return $this->belongsToMany('ride', 'user_car_ride');
}
```

user_car_ride is your pivot table name